# How to reload git hooks to template hooks

Tags: git, templates, github, gitlab, hook

I've edited some pre-existing hooks and would like to set them as default for when a repository is cloned. When I clone a new project I can see my hooks are available. Because I don't want to re-clone all my projects I want to be able to just reload the git template onto existing project. I ran `git init` in the same directory where `.git` is located but hooks never overwrite the pre-existing hooks in the project I was in. Does anyone know how to reload the template hooks onto existing cloned projects?

Comment: *I ran `git init` in the same directory where `.git` is located* - this should be the right way; but *the new hooks never made it to the project hook directory* - what do you mean by "project hook directory"? There's only one Git hooks directory for a repository, which is `.git/hooks/`; `git init` will not overwrite existing ones here, but will add *new* ones from the template.

Comment: @torek Hi, sorry I re-phrased the question above. I've actually edited a hook that already existed. Is there a way to have it overwrite the hooks that were already there with the template hooks? Ideally, without having to remove the hooks in the .git/hooks directory for the project.

Comment: Aha. No, Git doesn't overwrite existing files since they might be precious: it doesn't know that these are old templates, to be replaced with new ones. I'll add an alternative method as an answer (but it's painful once :-) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since files inside `.git` itself are not versioned, and Git does not know that, e.g., some existing `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file was actually installed from some earlier template, Git won't overwrite the existing file with a new one from an updated template.

There *is* a way to work around this, but it's slightly painful at least once.  This is: instead of having the "real" hook in `.git/hooks/name` for some *`name`*, you install, as `.git/hooks/name`, something that *indirects to* the real hook.

On Unix-ish systems, that's as simple as making `.git/hooks/name` a symbolic link to the desired hook, which can then live anywhere in the file system.  On other systems, where there must be an executable file in `.git/hooks/name`, you can make `.git/hooks/name` a single-line executable shell script (which is then generally two lines long) such as:

```
#! /bin/sh
exec /path/to/real/hook
```

and then once again the "real" hook can live anywhere.

#### Side note on relative paths

This particular example uses an absolute path.  Relative paths are possible, but then you must be careful about *relative to what.*

If you can use a symbolic link, you know that you are linking relative to the `.git/hooks` directory itself, so that a symlink from `.git/hooks/pre-commit` to `../../bin/pre-commit` "means" `some/path/to/.git/hooks/../../bin/pre-commit`, which, by path-name algebra and assuming `.git` and/or `.git/hooks` themselves are not symlinks, resolves to `some/path/to/bin/pre-commit`, i.e., the file `bin/pre-commit` in the work-tree.  But if you have a script, `../` is relative to the *current working directory* of the script, which is not related to the *location* of the script.

Fortunately, `git rev-parse` has some very useful abilities, such as:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

or:

```
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

which produce the top level work tree and the `.git` directory within it (as absolute or relative paths, but taking into account the current working directory of the process that runs `git rev-parse`).  Hence, if you want to run the `bin/pre-commit` file in the work-tree:

```
exec $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/bin/pre-commit
```

will do the trick.